# Cocoa (Snow Leopard) NSTextView's textStorage -setAttributes:range: removes characters!

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield, appkit

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I have a NSTextView and am registered as the delegate for its textStorage attribute.  When I receive `-textStorageDidProcessEditing:notification:` I'm trying to apply attributes to ranges of characters within the text.  It certainly does "something" to the characters, but not what I expect... they just disappear!

A heavily distilled code example.  This should make sure the second character in the text field is always red:

```
-(void)textStorageDidProcessEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSTextStorage *textStorage = [textView textStorage];
  if ([[textStorage string] length] > 1) {
    NSColor *color = [NSColor redColor];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:color, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    [textStorage setAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
  }
}
```

Instead, as I type the sequence "abcdefg" I get "a", then when I hit "b" seemingly nothing happens, then when I hit "cdefg" typing occurs as normal, making the end result "acdefg"... the "b" is missing!

If I start hitting backspace I have to hit backspace 7 times, as if the "b" is actually there, but just not being drawn (cursor stalls as it deletes the "b", then on the next backspace deletes the "a" as expected).

If I apply attributes to some default text in the view using the same `-setAttributes:range:` method *before* the view is drawn then it does exactly as I expect.

Any clues?  It seems like a fairly normal use of a `NSTextStorageDelegate` :)

I've tried calling `-setNeedsDisplay` on the text field to no avail.

Comment: I stumbled upon somebody else's code and they did this via the text view's layout manager:

`[[[textView textContainer] layoutManager] setTemporaryAttributes:attributes forCharacterRange:range];`

This is now working, right up until I hit the delete key, which causes an out of bounds Exception.

Comment: “If I start hitting backspace I have to hit backspace 7 times, as if the "b" is actually there, but just not being drawn (cursor stalls as it deletes the "b", then on the next backspace deletes the "a" as expected).” This sort of thing sounds like what happens when an application has an exception. Anything like that in your Console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.  Using NSTextStorage's `-addAttribute:value:range` works.  I still don't fully understand why but at least I can get over it and move on.

```
-(void)textStorageDidProcessEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
  // ... SNIP ...
  [textStorage addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                      value:[NSColor redColor]
                      range:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
}
```

Makes the code a bit less cluttered too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how relevant this is for you after so many years but I think the reason for it was that you were *setting* attributes with a dictionary which does not contain `NSFontAttributeName`, effectively removing it from the textview.

So I think this should work:

```
-(void)textStorageDidProcessEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSTextStorage *textStorage = [textView textStorage];
  if ([[textStorage string] length] > 1) {
    NSColor *color = [NSColor redColor];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:color, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [NSFont ...whatever...], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    [textStorage setAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
  }
}
```